# How to save generated PDF files to MySQL db using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a function which is generating PDF file using iText libary. My idea is that convert document to byte array but I always get a error: `com.itextpdf.text.Document@2805d0d4. The file cannot be found`.

Here is my PDF generation function:

```
    @Override
    public Boolean createdPDF() throws Exception {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("iTextHelloWorld.pdf"));

        document.open();
        Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 16, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Hello World", font);

        document.add(chunk);
        document.close();
        getByteArrayFromFile(document);

        return true;
    }
```

Here is my convert byte array from file function:

```
    private byte[] getByteArrayFromFile(Document handledDocument) throws IOException {
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         InputStream in = new FileInputStream(String.valueOf(handledDocument));
         byte[] buffer = new byte[500];

        int read = -1;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();

        Ticket newTicket = new Ticket();
        newTicket.setFileName("example");
        newTicket.setData(baos.toByteArray());
        ticketRepository.save(newTicket);

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

Ticket entity:

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    public class Ticket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String fileName;

    @Lob
    private byte[] data;

    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createAt;

    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how you can get a byte[] from PdfDocument:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Documentdocument = new Document();

PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

document.open();
Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 16, BaseColor.BLACK);
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Hello World", font);

document.add(chunk);
document.close(); 

pdfWriter.flush();

byte[] pdfAsBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```